# how to change the name of a file and the storage location on upload in django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-models, storage

I want to change an image name and it's storage location on upload.

I have

```
def name_func(instance, filename):
    blocks = filename.split('.')
    ext = blocks[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (instance.id, ext)
    return filename

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=name_func,null=True)

class Bar(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=name_func,null=True)
```

This uploads all the image files into the media folder and gives it the instance's id as a name.

Now I want the image files to be uploaded into two different subfolders. So I tried using the system filestorage:

```
fs_restaurant = FileSystemStorage(location='media/restaurant')
fs_bar = FileSystemStorage(location='media/bar')
```

and then change the `image_file` field to:

```
image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=name_func,null=True, storage=fs_restaurant)
```

and

```
image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=name_func,null=True, storage=bar)
```

Now this saves the files in the correct folder structure, however, when I click on the links in the admin's panel it's not linked correctly. This is obviously to the `name_func` function, but I am wondering if there is a way to correct that? In the doc I couldn't find a naming function in storage class.

Any ideas on how to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you need to prepend the subfolder onto your file name and return that.  In your database the filename should be the relative path to your file from the `STATIC_URL` or `MEDIA_URL`.

Here's an example I have where I generate a UUID for the filename and put it in a subfolder called `app_images`.

```
def unique_filename(instance, filename):
    path = 'app_images'
    filetype = os.path.splitext(instance.image.name)[1]
    new_filename = "{}{}".format(uuid.uuid4().hex, filetype)
    while AppImage.objects.filter(image__contains=new_filename).exists():
        new_filename = "{}{}".format(uuid.uuid4().hex, filetype)
    instance.filename = filename
    return os.path.join(path, new_filename)
```

Comment: but then I have to write two separate functions for the different classes, right?

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner That would work but you may not have to, you could potentially check the type of the instance argument i.e. `path = 'bar' if type(instance) == Bar else 'restaurant'`.  I have not tried this personally but it could work.